# Tikz: Start a further curve in the middle of another curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

the following code draws a bended between start and (4,4). I want to draw a further curve beginning from a point on that curve.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (start) {};
  \node at (10,0) (end) {};
  \node at (4,4) (foo) {};

  \draw (start) [->, >=stealth', thick] to (end);
  \draw (start) [out=15, in=180, -, >=stealth', thick] to (foo);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I solve this?

What I'm actually looking for is something like

```
\draw "begin from 0.1 on the way of the curve from start to foo" [-] to (6,2);
```

How can I track points on the curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `coordinate` and the `pos` option:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (start) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (end) at (10,0);
  \coordinate (foo) at (4,4);

  \draw[->, thick]  (start)to (end);
  \draw[-, thick] (start) to[out=15, in=180] coordinate[pos=0.3] (middle) (foo);
  \draw[red] (middle) -- (6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`pos` specifies the fraction along the path that the coordinate should appear. Note that if you use the `to` path, the `coordinate` has to come between the `to` and the final coordinate that sets the end point of the path. See Page 157 of the PGF 3.0.1a manual.

[image]